# jQuery DatePicker Range Clears Accompanying DatePicker on Select

Tags: jquery

I've setup a jquery datepicker using the examples from the docs, and configured them, but for some reason when I choose a start date it clears the second datepickers value.  If I comment out setting the minDate on the end date on select of the start date it doesn't happen.  Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
$('#searchFilterStartDate').datepicker({
    maxDate: '+0',
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

        var minDate = new Date(selectedDate);
        minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
        $('#searchFilterEndDate').datepicker('option', { 'minDate': minDate });
    }
});

$('#searchFilterEndDate').datepicker({
    maxDate: '+0'
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: What's the point of calling `setDate` with the value of `getDate` on the same `Date` object?

Comment: try  $('#searchFilterEndDate').datepicker( "option", "minDate", minDate);

Comment: It seems to be working fine. Just sets the date from 1st datepicker field to 2nd one. http://jsfiddle.net/p0Lacox1/

Comment: Yah @DinoMyte you're absolutely right.  It appears to only occur on first load of my view, which sets a default value='dateString' in the input.  After the first post to change the search it doesn't happen again no matter how many repeat searches I do.  I don't get it.

Comment: Is the default value in the same format that the datepicker uses?

Comment: Got it the format of the string is wrong I had it as m-d-Y and it has to be m/d/Y otherwise it clears on change.  I updated the http://jsfiddle.net/p0Lacox1/4/ to show the error in case it helps anyone else gets caught by it.